# How does @keypath in ReactiveCocoa work?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

How does @keypath in ReactiveCocoa 2.0 work?

[_self setValue:@(propertyValue) forKey:@keypath(MyClass.new, property)];

```
#define keypath(...) \
    metamacro_if_eq(1, metamacro_argcount(__VA_ARGS__))(keypath1(__VA_ARGS__))(keypath2(__VA_ARGS__))

#define keypath1(PATH) \
    (((void)(NO && ((void)PATH, NO)), strchr(# PATH, '.') + 1))

#define keypath2(OBJ, PATH) \
    (((void)(NO && ((void)OBJ.PATH, NO)), # PATH))
```